# Minor design issue with IE8 and "Explore Our Questions" display

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

Nothing major but I thought I would point out a display issue in IE8, best demonstrated with a screenshot:

[image]

That text in these tags appears to run outside of them and not display correctly. Likely a minor fix, and I undertand IE8 isn't a major compatibility issue but I'm sure there's others out there, like myself, stuck on it due to company policy! Blergh!

Comment: Quick comment for paging @Jin !

Comment: IE 8 is not a supported browser. We support current and previous versions (so, 9 and 10 at the moment, for IE).

Comment: @Oded - Just letting you know... that is the exact phrase I always dreamed saying to some of our clients ^_^'